# Why does time returned by [NSDate date] differ from my current time?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, timezone, nsdate

hi all 
I am in India.And I have used the following code to get the current date.

```
[NSDate date]
```

it displaying the "2011-01-20 06:51:35 +0000" but actual time is "2011-01-20 12:21:35 +0000"
.Please tell me how to get the current date.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, the actual time is 2011-01-20 06:51:35 +0000 and YOUR local time is 2011-01-20 12:21:35 +0530. Your local time would /never/ be +0000 as that's GMT

Comment: you should accept the answer if it helps,so that developers are encouraged to help fellow developers...

Comment: Should I assume that [NSDate date] returns the current date&time in GMT0?

Comment: it returns GMT + 00000

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use Date Formatter for this purpose.Below is the sample code for that.

```
NSDate *testDate=[NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM DD YY hh:mm"];//You can set your required format here
NSString *dt = [formatter stringFromDate:testDate];
[formatter release];

NSString *strDateTaken=dt;
```

Cheers

Comment: Should I assume that [NSDate date] returns the current date&time in GMT0?

Answer (score 3):

What does “actual time” mean? The current time in your time zone? Considering the time values given I’d guess that the first one is GMT and you want IST (+5:30). (See [Time zones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zones) on Wikipeda.) Depends on what you want to do with the date – if you just want a formatted date and time in your current time zone, Aditya’s answer should work.

Answer (score 0):

To Find Current date and difference between current date and Given date...its working code

```
NSDate *testDate=[NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatterNew = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatterNew setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss "]; 
NSString *dt = [formatterNew stringFromDate:testDate];
NSString *strDateTaken=dt;
NSLog(@"Date=%@",strDateTaken);
[formatterNew release]; // This line can be removed if you are using ARC

NSDateFormatter *tempFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
[tempFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *toDate = [tempFormatter dateFromString:strDateTaken];
NSLog(@"Current Date ==%@",toDate);

NSDateFormatter *tempFormatter1 = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
[tempFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *startdate = [tempFormatter1 dateFromString:@"30-08-2011 16:25:00"];
NSLog(@"Last Date ==%@",startdate);

int i = [startdate timeIntervalSince1970];  
int j = [toDate timeIntervalSince1970];
double X = j-i;
int days=(int)((double)X/(3600.0*24.00));


NSLog(@" Difference :%d",days);
```